# nextLine() skips line at end of while loop. Lose data

Tags: java, while-loop, text-files, java.util.scanner

I am trying to only run nextLine() at the end of every run of the loop so that it starts the loop with the new line each iteration through, but at the end of the last run, i dont want it to run the nextLine() because  it skips the data i need for the rest of my program. how do i fix this?

```
        String hasInt = fileIn.nextLine();

        while(Character.isDigit(hasInt.charAt(0)))
            {
                data = hasInt.split(",");
                info = Integer.parseInt(data[0]);
                def = data[1];
                case = data[2];
                free = data[3];

                Case newCase = new Case(info, def, case, free);
                miner.addCase(newCase);
                hasInt = fileIn.nextLine();
            }
```

Well combining it all into that for loop seemed to work, that got me all the way through the loop, and seemed to work, but now at the start of the method it got stuck in an infinite loop

```
   while(fileIn.hasNextLine())
      {
        if(fileIn.hasNext("[A-Za-z]+"))
         {
```

Comment: You cannot use `case` as a variable name, this code will not compile; please edit and paste the real code

Answer (score 1):

```
    do {
        String hasInt = fileIn.nextLine();
        if (!Character.isDigit(hasInt.charAt(0)) {
           break; 
        }
        // rest of your code here            
    } while(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try merging the statements into a for loop:

```
for(
    String hasInt = fileIn.nextLine();
    Character.isDigit(hasInt.charAt(0));
    hasInt = fileIn.nextLine()
) {
    data = hasInt.split(",");
    info = Integer.parseInt(data[0]);
    def = data[1];
    case = data[2];
    free = data[3];

    Case newCase = new Case(info, def, case, free);
    miner.addCase(newCase);
}
```

Comment: code is stuck in infinite loop at top of method now, i posted the code its stuck at?

Comment: If you're having a new problem, I suggest posting it as a separate question with **all the relevant code** in it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how clean it would be but; it seems that you could use hasInt after the while loop to get the value that you do not want to skip.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you will not loss the data since the data you read last is in the hasInt variable. So use it after the while loop.

```
String hasInt = fileIn.nextLine();

    while(Character.isDigit(hasInt.charAt(0)))
        {
            data = hasInt.split(",");
            info = Integer.parseInt(data[0]);
            def = data[1];
            case = data[2];
            free = data[3];

            Case newCase = new Case(info, def, case, free);
            miner.addCase(newCase);
            hasInt = fileIn.nextLine();
        }
     //use the hasInt variable here to get the last read data...
```